# SQLite: Does table relation foreign key automatically change in all tables that relait to it?

Tags: database, sqlite, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

Lets look at simple example (simplified example from [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/796.aspx)):

```
CREATE TABLE [Employees](
        [EmployeeID] nchar(5) primary key,
        [ReportsTo] nchar(5) NULL,
    constraint fk_Employees_Employees foreign key(ReportsTo) references Employees(EmployeeID)
);

CREATE TABLE [Orders](
        [OrderID] integer primary key autoincrement,
        [EmployeeID] int NULL
    constraint fk_Orders_Employees foreign key (EmployeeID) references Employees (EmployeeID)
);
```

we have 2 tables, one that has items that are inter related and one that relates to items from first table.

Imagine we have some "Employees" and some "Orders" what will happen to orders that and employees that relate to some `EmployeeID` when it is changed?

Say we had `Tom` and order `1` that related to `tom`. We changed `Tom` to `Ben`. Will order `1` be related to `Ben` now automatically via hidden from us SQLite magik, or we have to explicetly tall all orders that belonged to `Tom` that they are `Ben`'s now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am correctly understanding your requirements; if all the orders that belongs to TOM are changed to BEN then you have to update the table [Orders] as:

**Case1:** If TOM is no more in the office & TOM is replaced by BEN then:

```
assuming that TOM's employeeId is 1 BEN's employeeId is 33

UPDATE [Orders]
SET    EmployeeId = 33
WHERE  EmployeeId = 1
```

**Case2:** If TOM's EmployeeId is changed from 1 to 33 in Employees Table then you have to update the orders table also (You asked & i am replying here, question is why you need to change TOM's EMployee Id?):

```
assuming that TOM's employeeId is changed from 1 is 33

UPDATE [Orders]
SET    EmployeeId = 33
WHERE  EmployeeId = 1
```

Comment: So this means if we had only TOM (`1`) in `Employees` and changed it to `33` in that table, we still have to update all ex TOMs items in `Orders` table?

Comment: If TOM ID was changed from 1 to 33 in Employee Table then you have to Update all the ex TOMs items in Orders Table.